# Add multiple variables in a JS loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have multiple inputs (class `.fat-calc1` to `.fat-calc24`) and a result place (class `fat-result`). I want to make a loop that adds inputs (`.fat-calc1 + .fat-calc2 + ... + .fat-calc24`) and displays that in the result `div`.

```html
<div class='fat-calc-col'>
  <input type='number' name='fat-calc1"' class='fat-calc fat-calc1'>
  <input type='number' name='fat-calc2"' class='fat-calc fat-calc2'>
  <input type='number' name='fat-calc2"' class='fat-calc fat-calc2'>
  ...
  <div class='calc-result fat-result'></div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".fat-calc-col").children().on('input', function(e){

    var fat = [];
    let result = "";
    
    for (let x = 1; x <= 24; x++) {
        fat[x] = parseFloat($(".fat-calc" + x).val());
        fat[x] = fat[x] ? fat[x] : 0;
        result += fat[x];
    }

    $(".fat-result").text(result);
    
});
```

When you type 1 into `fat-calc1` and 3 into `fat-calc2` the result it not 4, but 130000000000000000000000. I was trying to add parseFloat to basically everything I could, but it didn't work. Why does that happen? How to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to add the `fat-calc` values? If so, then `result` can't start as a string, which will append numbers as a string, instead of adding them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add it all to string. Change it
`let result = "";`
to it
`let result = 0;`

Answer (score 3):

If all you need to do is sum the values of the `.fat-calc` fields, then your code is far more complicated than it needs to be. You don't need an array, or a `for` loop over 24 arbitrary values.

To do what you require just need to loop through the `input` elements and sum their values. This can be done using `reduce()`

```js
const $result = $('.fat-result');
const $inputs = $('.fat-calc').on('input', () => {
  const sum = $inputs.get().reduce((acc, el) => acc += +el.value, 0);
  $result.text(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="fat-calc1" class="fat-calc fat-calc1" />
<input type="number" name="fat-calc2" class="fat-calc fat-calc2" />
<input type="number" name="fat-calc2" class="fat-calc fat-calc2" />

<div class="calc-result fat-result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `130000000000000000000000` is your output instead of simply `4` is because you are concatenating strings instead of adding integers.

What you think your code is doing is `1 + 3 + 0 + 0 + 0 + ... + 0 = 4`, but in reality, you're doing `"" + 1 + 3 + 0 + 0 + ... + 0`. Since a string is starting the chain, the final result will be a string. It evaluates like this:

```js
"" + 1 + 3 + 0 + 0 + ... + 0
"1" + 3 + 0 + 0 + ... + 0
"13" + 0 + 0 + ... + 0
"130" + 0 + 0 + ... + 0
"1300" + 0 + 0 + ... + 0
"130000000000000000000000"
```

One way you can fix it is to make sure `result = 0` at the start. Try this code:

```js
$(".fat-calc-col").children().on('input', function(e){

    var fat = [];
    let result = 0; // 0, not ""
    
    for (let x = 1; x <= 24; x++) {
        fat[x] = parseFloat($(".fat-calc" + x).val());
        fat[x] = fat[x] ? fat[x] : 0;
        result += fat[x];
    }

    $(".fat-result").text(result);
    
});
```

But this is also unnecessary. You can use the [answer by Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74005825/14469685) for a better setup. Code here for reference (click to expand):

```js
const $result = $('.fat-result');
const $inputs = $('.fat-calc').on('input', () => {
  const sum = $inputs.get().reduce((acc, el) => acc += +el.value, 0);
  $result.text(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="fat-calc1" class="fat-calc fat-calc1" />
<input type="number" name="fat-calc2" class="fat-calc fat-calc2" />
<input type="number" name="fat-calc2" class="fat-calc fat-calc2" />

<div class="calc-result fat-result"></div>
```